# With jQuery, how to get the attribute for an HTML element i.e. not the first element of a matched set?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I know you use the `attr` method to get the attribute for the *first item* in a matched set, e.g. `$('input').attr('name')` gives you the name attribute for the first matched input element.

But how do I get the attribute directly from an HTML element, e.g. `$('input')[0]`? I'd like to do something like `$('input')[0].attr('name')` but that doesn't work, as `attr` is only a method of jQuery matched sets, not the items within matched sets.

(By the way, this has come up because I'd like to pass items from within a matched set to a function, and be able to see the attributes of that item within the function.)

Comment: $($('input')[0]).attr('name')

Comment: @jeschafe that's redundant, you dont need the extra `$()`

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Yeah but if you wanted to select the second element in the set say, $($('input')[2]).attr('name') then it's not.  Was just giving him an example related to his own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by `[0]` you simply want to get a specific element from a matched set, used `eq()`:

```
$(selector).eq(0).attr('name');
```

Will get the `name` attribute of the first element in the set returned by the `selector`. Of course, the the `0` can be replaced by the index number of any element returned by that selector.

Similarly, you could use the `:eq()` selector:

```
$('div:eq(0)').attr('name');
```

Or, if `selector` is a variable:

```
$(selector + ':eq(0)').attr('name');
```

As Alnitak notes, in the comments below:

> If you're going to use eq, use `.eq(n)` rather than `:eq(n)` so that the browser can use `querySelectorAll()` - the latter is a jQuery extension.

Of course, you could, for certain names, or properties, just fall back to the DOM methods:

```
$(selector)[0].name;
```

Or:

```
$(selector)[0].getAttribute('name');
```

References:

- [`:eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/).
- [`eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/).

Comment: if you're going to use `eq`, use `.eq(n)` rather than `:eq(n)` so that the browser can use `querySelectorAll` - the latter is a jQuery extension.

Comment: Yeah, I should've clarified/specified that, really. *editing* and thanks! =)

Comment: Thanks for such a thorough and multifaceted answer!

Answer (score 1):

When you have an actual HTML object, you can still JQuery-ify it by wrapping it in $(element), then have access to attr()

```
var secondThing = $('input')[1]
foo(secondThing)

function foo(element){
var elem = $(element);
var name = elem.attr('name');

//or
name = element.getAttribute('name')

}
```

Comment: that's horribly inefficient.  If you have an actual **DOM** object, just use native DOM methods on it when you can.

Comment: @Alnitak added another way, but from the question, it sounded like he wanted to use jQuery's attr():  "I'd like to do something like $('input')[0].attr('name') but that doesn't work"